# How to compare the variables at same index of multiple lists in python

Tags: python-3.x

[y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbQ82.png) I have multiple lists from which I want to find the maximum number at same index.

```
i = 0
list = [""]

# open file and read the content in a list
with open('/media/saqib/Study/Angular/weatherfiles/weatherfiles/Murree_weather_2004_Aug.txt', 'r') as filehandle:  

    for line in filehandle:

        # remove linebreak which is the last character of the string
        list.append(line.strip().split(','))

        print list[i]
        i = i+1

      # add item to the list
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? What ideas do you have for achieving what you want to do? Also, you mention multiple lists, but in the example code that you provided, there's only one.

Comment: The loop should be `for line in filehandle.readlines():`

Comment: Could you give an example of your file with expected output?

Comment: Yes I have did you can see

Answer (score 0):

The following program should accomplish what you want, if I understand that you are looking to find the maximum number at a specific index. It is commented within to explain what it is doing:

```
# Create a function to find the maximum number
# Takes in a list of lists, and an index
def find_maximum_number(master_list, ind):
    # Set the "max" variable, and the list that contains it
    big = 0
    max_list = []

    # Loop through your list of lists
    for arr in master_list:
        # If the value at the current list's index is bigger than the max, record it
        # and the list it came from
        if arr[ind] > big:
            big = arr[ind]
            max_list = arr
        else:
            # If not, keep going
            continue

    # Return the biggest and the maximum list
    return big, max_list

# Main program
def main():
    # Create three example lists
    example_list_1 = [3,4,11,2,3,4]
    example_list_2 = [3,4,12, 22, 100, 11,2,3,4]
    example_list_3 = [3,4,11,2,3,4, 684, 3, 0, 1, 12, 39, 8, 44]

    # Combine them
    combined_list = []
    combined_list.append(example_list_1)
    combined_list.append(example_list_2)
    combined_list.append(example_list_3)

    # Run the program, capture the results
    biggest, thelist = find_maximum_number(combined_list, 4)

    # Print them out
    print("The maximum at index 4 was: ", biggest)
    print("The maximum was of the list: ", thelist)

main() 

# Prints:
# The maximum at index 4 was:  100
# The maximum was of the list:  [3, 4, 12, 22, 100, 11, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood your question, but this is a simple example:

```
A = [5, 8, 2, 0, 9]
B = [3, 6, 8, 5, 3]
C = [1, 3, 6, 9, 5]
```

My understanding is that you want to have a list with maximum number of each index. If it is the case, you can run this:

```
[max(a, b, c) for a, b, c in zip(A, B, C)]
```

The output will be:

```
output: [5, 8, 8, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Basically I read the data from a file in list format , now I want to do some calculations on the data by comparing the values at same index i.e. I want to find the maximum, average ,